# Super User question about manufacturer support web site resources: on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics

Is the following question on- or off-topic for Super User:

https://superuser.com/questions/123357/service-tag-urls

I choose to interpret the FAQ liberally, and the question as I see it **does** relate to computer hardware and software: it's asking about computer manufacturer support resources.  When I have a problem with my computer hardware, that's the first place I go *then* Super User.  (Well actually - we go to Google first!)

@Josh K, in his comments at the question above, quotes the FAQ and points to other [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43639/off-topic-questions-on-super-user-some-give-and-take-closed) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39615/superuser-website-applications-policy) that seem to be talking about *web applications*.  I don't think that's the case here.  So:

**Is it fair to ask a question at Super User about how to most efficiently access support resources (e.g. drivers, BIOS updates, tools, manuals) from a computer manufacturer's web site?**  Many super users are de-facto support personnel for family and friends.  Wouldn't it be handy to have shortcuts to computer manufacturer resources for specific service tags?

We're on a slippery slope if any question about a web site is a target for closure.  I think the >3000 community ought to be more liberal in interpretation of the FAQ when a question clearly has some on-topic content and merit.  The FAQ is *necessarily* terse and therefore vague because nobody wants it to be a 500+ page document with law-like precision.  I don't believe the FAQ is terse to justify strict interpretation.

*p.s. I'd have counted myself in that >3000 community but my rep got nerfed after the recent recalc. :-(*

Comment: +1. I'm simply trying to interpret the FAQ as other people have defined it.

Comment: I simply tend to ignore these kind of questions, since it's such a grey area. I prefer killing Facebook questions!

Comment: There are Facebook questions?

Answer (score 5):

I'm also not active enough on Super User to make any kind of judgement, but my 2 cents: I would definitely rule it in because it is a useful resource in terms of the area that Super User is meant to cover: Hardware and Software support.

It is beneficial for Super User as a whole in that it provides a resource that pre-empts questions that would be (rightly or wrongly) treated as valid ones ("I reinstalled my xyz laptop, but now the abc doesn't work anymore. What do I need to download?") it would also be a great linking target in case such questions come up.

Answer (score 4):

We've had quite a lot of debate about Super User and the website-questions-policy.  Here are two of the more major threads:

- [High reputation users having trouble understanding Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38391/high-reputation-users-having-trouble-understanding-super-user)
- [Superuser website applications policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39615/superuser-website-applications-policy)

That's the basis of current policy, so start there.

> Is it fair to ask a question at Super User about how to most efficiently access support resources (e.g. drivers, BIOS updates, tools, manuals) from a computer manufacturer's web site?

Yes, it's fair *to ask*.  But if the question is more about *how to use the manufacturer's website* than *supporting the hardware*, it may fall afoul of the website policy.

Resolving this is simple: don't ask how to use the manufacturer's website; ask how to fix the problem hardware.  (Or software.  Whatever.)

Comment: +1 Well said ~quack

Answer (score 3):

That's a website support question. Ruling it **out.**

Just because it's about support for computer parts doesn't skate the fact that yes, this is essentially, "Are there tricks for this site?"

Comment: i tend to agree.  as a "tools in the IT toolbag" sort of question, tho, i think it could have a home on SF, and have voted to migrate it there instead of closing outright.  (i'm not familiar enough with SF to know whether they'll just close it or not; i just feel it's not appropriate for SU, and if SF gets it they can decide for themselves.)

Comment: Agreed - my vote closed the question.

Comment: @~quack: I give it 7:3 odds for survival on SF.  It might live, but depends on the mood of the community when it's asked.  Questions that skirt the help desk/desktop support line frequently fall off the side of the cliff.

Comment: @squillman: thanks, that gives me at least a bit of insight into how SF might look at the desktop support type questions.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I'm inclined to say *no*, but I'm not active enough in SU to be able to make that judgement. However, I don't think SU is suitable, because

1. Techincally, it could be interpreted as a web application. (Yes, I know this is a poor argument)
2. The manufacturer's support web site would probably be a better place, even if the question is about that very web site. *(META)!*